# OJDBC 14 implicite date conversion?

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc, ojdbc

We are using ojdbc14_10.1.0.2.jar with a Java/J2EE application (that use directly JDBC) and JDK5, but when we tried to migrate into ojdbc5-11.2.0.3.jar we encountered an issue related to some sql request (jdbc) that doesn't work anymore.

The pseudo SQL request is :

```
select *
from quotas q 
where q.datdeb<='2013-09-05' and q.datfin>='2013-09-05' 
and q.datdeb is not null and q.datfin is not null order by ....;
```

The NLS parameters for date is : 
DD/MM/RR

Which is not compatible with the date format giving as parameter in the request.

Everything worked fine when we were using ojdbc14; apparently it does an implicite conversion for the date.

For information, The oracle Database is 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to use the to_date function with an appropriate date mask to get around the problem.

```
select *
from quotas q 
where q.datdeb<=to_date('2013-09-05','yyyy-mm-dd') and q.datfin>=to_date('2013-09-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
and q.datdeb is not null and q.datfin is not null order by ....;
```

Comment: Yes of course this is a good solution, but i forgot to mention that the Java/J2EE application contains a lot of sql request with parameters as date, so the impact will be huge and there is a great regression risk. Because the application is running under Apache Tomcat, is there any Tomcat arguments that could implicitly convert the sql date argument before sending them to Oracle ?

Comment: What is the data type of quotas.datdeb, quotas.datfin? Also, is the parameter a date or a string?

Comment: quotas.datdeb, quotas.datfin are Dates in database and the giving parameters are dates too (java.util.Date), so in the Java/J2EE application they are converted to YYYY-MM-DD but the database accept the DD/MM/RR format date. So when we were using OJDBC14 we had no problem (i guess OJDBC14 converted implicitly the sql argument dates) but when we migrate into OJDBC5 we start to encounter this issue.